# Is an uncensored release of "Dakara, Boku wa H! ga Dekinai" released yet

Tags: boku-h

Due to the extreme amount of unclothed female chests in Dakara, Boku wa H! ga Dekinai, those black stripes almost killed the fun of watching the series.

I would rather have the [godiva hair](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GodivaHair) (they did it in some shots), or the [lens flare](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LensFlareCensor)/[mist](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CensorSteam) of the first episodes, or even the [barbie doll](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BarbieDollAnatomy) treatment, but those black strips were too much in the last episodes.

I am aware that probably the DVD are uncensored, if that is the case, I just want to confirm it.

Comment: There is already a DVD release in the US, as far as I'm aware all western releases are Uncensored.

Comment: @Tsugumori-704 if you are answering, do not do it in the comments.

Comment: I didn't feel that my reply was useful enough to be an 'answer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All six BD/DVD volumes of *Dakara, Boku wa H ga Dekinai* have been released in Japan, and [Volume 6 was released on February 20th, 2013](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%83%95%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81H%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%80%82#BD_.2F_DVD). The BD version is uncensored as far as it is allowed for a non R18+ work.

Here are a few comparison screenshots from [Kira Reviews](http://www.kira-reviews.com/blog/archives/category/dakara-boku-wa-h-ga-dekinai). TV version on the left, uncensored BD version on the right. Both images are from volume 1 (episode 1 and 2).

[image: TV (Episode 1)] [image: BD (Episode 1)]
[image: TV (Episode 2)] [image: BD (Episode 2)]